# Error when using an awkward array with an index array

Tags: python-3.x, awkward-array

I currently have a list of values and an awkward array of integer values. I want the same dimension awkward array, but where the values are the indices of the "values" arrays corresponding with the integer values of the awkward array. For instance:

```
values = ak.Array(np.random.rand(100))
arr = ak.Array((np.random.randint(0, 100, 33), np.random.randint(0, 100, 125)))
```

I want something like values[arr], but that gives the following error:

```
>>> values[arr]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\awkward\highlevel.py", line 943, in __getitem__
    return ak._util.wrap(self._layout[where], self._behavior)
ValueError: cannot fit jagged slice with length 2 into RegularArray of size 100
```

If I run it with a loop, I get back what I want:

```
>>> values = ([values[i] for i in arr])
>>> values
[<Array [0.842, 0.578, 0.159, ... 0.726, 0.702] type='33 * float64'>, <Array [0.509, 0.45, 0.202, ... 0.906, 0.367] type='125 * float64'>]
```

Is there another way to do this, or is this it? I'm afraid it'll be too slow for my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid Python for loops for performance, note that the first line casts a NumPy array as Awkward with [ak.from_numpy](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.from_numpy.html) (no loop, very fast):

```py
>>> values = ak.Array(np.random.rand(100))
```

but the second line iterates over data in Python (has a slow loop):

```py
>>> arr = ak.Array((np.random.randint(0, 100, 33), np.random.randint(0, 100, 125)))
```

because a tuple of two NumPy arrays is not a NumPy array. It's a generic iterable, and the constructor falls back to [ak.from_iter](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.from_iter.html).

On your main question, the reason that `arr` doesn't slice `values` is because `arr` is a jagged array and `values` is not:

```py
>>> values
<Array [0.272, 0.121, 0.167, ... 0.152, 0.514] type='100 * float64'>
>>> arr
<Array [[15, 24, 9, 42, ... 35, 75, 20, 10]] type='2 * var * int64'>
```

Note the types: `values` has type `100 * float64` and `arr` has type `2 * var * int64`. There's no rule for `values[arr]`.

Since it looks like you want to slice `values` with `arr[0]` and then `arr[1]` (from your list comprehension), it could be done in a vectorized way by duplicating `values` for each element of `arr`, then slicing.

```py
>>> # The np.newaxis is to give values a length-1 dimension before concatenating.
>>> duplicated = ak.concatenate([values[np.newaxis]] * 2)
>>> duplicated
<Array [[0.272, 0.121, ... 0.152, 0.514]] type='2 * 100 * float64'>
```

Now `duplicated` has length 2 and one level of nesting, just like `arr`, so `arr` can slice it. The resulting array also has length 2, but the length of each sublist is the length of each sublist in `arr`, rather than 100.

```py
>>> duplicated[arr]
<Array [[0.225, 0.812, ... 0.779, 0.665]] type='2 * var * float64'>
>>> ak.num(duplicated[arr])
<Array [33, 125] type='2 * int64'>
```

If you're scaling up from 2 such lists to a large number, then this would eat up a lot of memory. Then again, the size of the output of this operation would also scale as "length of `values`" × "length of `arr`". If this "2" is not going to scale up (if it will be at most thousands, not millions or more), then I wouldn't worry about the speed of the Python for loop. Python scales well for thousands, but not billions (depending, of course, on the size of the things being scaled!).

Comment: The "for" loop is definitely too time consuming; I have 1100+ files to crawl over and it hangs on just one of them (each file has 10s of thousands of events with hundreds of hits, so we're in the millions).

Comment: I gave it a try, but now I'm having another issue related to this one. In my data, I have awkward arrays from a *.root file using uproot. The "arr" in this case is not defined as integers, but they are of integer value. How do I convert the awkward array to integers? Maybe this should be a separate question. I know it can be done in numpy with .astype(int); does that exist in awkward?

Comment: Since the main question is answered, I'm going to make a new question on the integer bit. Thanks again!